# copy file from windows to android using batch

Tags: android, windows, batch-file, copy, tablet

I want create batch process to update files on android tablet (for non-experienced user) via USB port. These devices eg. Motorola Xoom is recognized as "Portable device" and don't have a letter to identify itself. On explorer there is path eg "\Xoom\Internal Storage\".

Problem is that i don't know how to get *suffix* of tablet path.

`copy file.ext ???/directory/file.ext`

I tried to use adb push (which works, using getExternalStorage() as path of device path "/mnt/sdcard") however there is required to enable debug mode, therefore this is not optimal solution. I dont want to force user to enable this mode, run batch process and then disable debug mode.

Thanks

---

Just another few notes:

- key words to describe problem reduced to "get path to portable device"
- android version on devices is 3.0.x - (api level 11) not enough to use     `android.hardware.usb` package

Comment: What keeps you from using Wifi or Bluetooth instead?

Comment: It should be able update itself from pc directly. Just put usb key with files to one port and device to another one. Run batch and that's all.

Comment: So you want to connect the USB key to the tablet and then run the batch file that's on the USB key which will update the files on the tablet with the ones from the USB key, right?

Comment: i didn't think about this.. however this can be solution too

Comment: That is what I understand from your post..

Comment: i thought connect usb key to pc and also connect tablet to pc. sorry if i wrote it confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `MOUNTVOL` command to mount the USB drive, identified by its GUID, on a specific mount point, independently of the available drive letters.

```
 MOUNTVOL C:\XOOM \\?\Volume{a000351d-dbaa-11e0-bdaa-020255061358}\
```

and then

```
 copy file.ext c:\XOOM\directory\file.ext
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I could not figure how to autmaticaly detect GUID. At the end I decide solve update problem by writting copy program in C# that use PortableDeviceApi library to connect to device. As template i used this source [link](http://cgeers.com/2011/08/13/wpd-transferring-content/)

Comment: Don't work in Windows 11. Do you know any solution?

Answer (score 3):

To get the GUID, start up device manager, and select "portable device".  Select your phone from within there.

Properties, Details, "Device class guid".